# Having trouble with adding strings... (c++)

Tags: c++, string, operators

For some reason my source file will not compile because of my toString function. It claims it cannot recognize the + symbol to append strings. Here's my code:

```
string s = "{symbol = " + symbol + ", qty = " + qty + ", price = " + price + "}";
```

symbol, qty, and price are variables in the class

I get the following message from the compiler...

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 55ms)

mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Stock.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Stock.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Stock.o Stock.cpp
Stock.cpp: In member function 'std::string Stock::toString()':
Stock.cpp:56: error: no match for 'operator+' in 'std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((const char*)", qty = ")) + ((Stock*)this)->Stock::qty'
make: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Stock.o] Error 1


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 261ms)
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: What are the types of `symbol`, `qty` and `price`?

Comment: symbol - string |
qty - int |
price - double

Comment: You did `include <string>` I assume?

Comment: yes i did include <string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `std::string::operator+` on int types, use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "{symbol = " << symbol << ", qty = " << qty << ", price = " << price << "}";

std::string s = ss.str();
```

Or use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) if you use C++11 and boost::lexical_cast to cast integer types to string first:

```
std::string s = "{symbol = " + symbol + ", qty = " + std::to_string(qty) 
                + ", price = " + std::to_string(price) + "}";
```

Comment: Make sure to add some error checking though if the stream fails.

Comment: I used the first of the two described methods and it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `qty` and `price` are ints or something similar you can do the following (in C++11):

```
string s = "{symbol = " + symbol + ", qty = " + std::to_string(qty) + ", price = " + std::to_string(price) + "}";
```

[example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48efP6%243)

Comment: he appears to be on OSX, so C++11 support is far from guaranteed

Comment: Depending on the versions of OS X and the compiler used C++11 support on OS X is great. It comes with libc++, an essentially complete C++11 library including things missing from even vs2012's library, and the latest version of clang has nearly complete C++11 language support; The only feature I'm aware it's missing that anyone else has is inheriting constructors (implemented only in GCC 4.8).